Given the CDF of a discrete random variable X, what is the value of $P\{X<2|X\ne1\}$?
The CDF of a discrete random variable X is as follows:
\begin{equation}
  F(x)=
  \begin{cases}
    0, & x<-1\\
    0.4, & -1\le x<1\\
    0.8, & 1\le x<3\\
    1, & x\ge3\\
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
what is the value of $P\{X<2|X\ne1\}$?

My thought:
Since $x$ is a discrete variable, we can list the $P(x)$ for each integer between $-1$ and $3$, and they are actually all $0.2$.
Then, $P\{x<2|x\ne1\}$ = $\Large\frac{P\{x<2, x\ne1\}}{P\{x\ne 1\}}$.
$P\{x<2, x\ne1\} = P(-1) + P(0) = 0.2 + 0.2 = 0.4$
$P\{x\ne 1\} = P(-1) + P(0) + P(2) + P(3) = 0.8$
So I think the value to the question is $\frac{1}{2}$. But the answer is $\frac{2}{3}$, and I'm not sure where it went wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

$P(X = -1) = F(-1) - F(-1^{-}) = 0.4-0 = 0.4$

You have all the probabilities wrong. $P(-1)=0.4$, $P(0)=P(2)=0$, $P(1)=0.4$ and $P(3)=0.2$
